# Negative voltage across ground points under load

Tags: voltage-regulator

All,

I have a circuit with an Exar XRP7659 5v 1.5A regulator and a Torex XC6210B 3.3V LDO Regulator. I am using this circuit to charge USB devices at full current and have noticed that when the device is charging I get negative voltage from any two ground points on the breadboard.

It appears that this negative voltage is coming from the GND pin on the USB port, as I read the highest negative voltage there, but it's seen throughout the circuit. The result is that the LDO goes slightly under voltage to 2.8 - 3.1 volts. The LDO returns to 3.3v when the USB device is unplugged. The issue is not apparent when using a 5V 1.5A power source but this results in ~4.4V out of the 5V regulator, which is unacceptable. I am using (and have tried multiple) a 12V 1.25A DC input source.

**What could cause this negative voltage and how do I resolve it?**

Here's a schematic for my circuit
[image: Power Schematic]

Comment: You say you are seeing negative voltage on ground. Question: measured against what? In other words, where is your other meter probe connected? If it is on another ground point, this indicates resistance between different points on your ground.

Comment: Additional question: why are you feeding 3.3V into a USB device? USB is always 5V. Feeding 3.3V in is not likely to work well.

Comment: Aha! You're right - I measured against the ground point of another DC wall wart and measured no voltage across the two grounds. There is however 50-60k ohms of resistance when the device is charging and no resistance at all when the USB device is unplugged. As per your USB question, sorry if I was unclear but I am charging off the 5V - The 3.3V has no load on it and is for an unintegrated portion of this circuit.

Comment: Thangs are still unclear. How are you measuring resistance? You cannot measure resistance on a powered circuit with a standard meter. Turn off the power and measure resistance between the ground points. Most likely you'll see a few ohms or tens of ohms in your ground path. That is dropping the voltage when under load (Ohm's law: V=IR).

Comment: I measured resistance with the circuit powered on initially. You're correct, there's about .5 Ohms of resistance from ground to ground on the unpowered circuit. When I power the circuit, resistance stays about the same (1 Ohm) but when I hook up the USB device to charge, resistance jumps anywhere between 50k-110k Ohms.

Comment: To clarify, all measurements were taken from the same two ground points on the circuit; they are the two which are furthest from each other.

Comment: Again, any resistance measurements with the circuit powered are invalid - ignore these. You have a half-ohm in your ground circuit. You're dropping 0.6V on the 1/2 ohm which indicates 1.2A current flow (Ohm's Law). Fix the resistance and you're good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you have about a 0.5 Ω resistance in your ground wiring. You are losing about 0.6 volts when under load. Ohm's Law (V=I*R ==> I=V/R) says I=~0.6/~0.5 = about 1.2 amps flowing through that ground. It all adds up.

Fix the resistance in the ground wiring and you'll fix your voltage drop.